# SVG as <object> loses attribute "fill" when moved with .insertBefore()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am setting a fill attribute on SVG images, but after they are moved with .insertBefore(), they revert back to default and I am no longer able to select the right elements to re-apply the fill attribute.

---

I am using images as SVG through `<object>`.
This gives me a structure like:

```
<object class='blah1'>
  #document
    <svg>
      <path>
```

or

```
<object class='blah1'>
  #document
    <svg>
      <path>
        <g>
          <g>
          etc
```

depending on the image.

I am using the "fill" attribute to change the color of the SVG images with javascript/jquery, using `.setAttribute()`, which requires some roundabout way of selecting the right element especially due to the #document part. This works fine.

These `<object>` elements are nested under more `<div>` elements, and multiple rows of these div's are nested under `<li>` elements and a top level `<ul>`, like so:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <object>
        etc.
  <li>
    <div>
      <object>
        etc.
  etc.
</ul>
```

I am then sorting these rows based on a number by taking the `<li>` and using .insertBefore().

Once the list element is moved around: the previously set "fill" attribute no longer applies (the svg reverts back to black), and I am no longer able to select the right elements to change the "fill" attribute.
I have tried using the methods I have used before to change the fill and they do not work. I have tried figuring out a different way but I am unable to make it past the #document in a way that makes sense.

Does .insertBefore() somehow reset the entire object/svg?
How can I change the fill attribute of the SVG after it is moved with .insertBefore()?

Comment: On what browser? Please create a [mcve] if more than one, otherwise submit a bug report to the browser's bugtracker if only one.

Comment: @RobertLongson On chrome. I dont have any other browser available for testing besides IE, and IE has many other incompatibilities that I can't easily test that part cleanly.

Comment: @RobertLongson having a hard time getting SVG objects to work how I have them in JS Fiddle...

Comment: Maybe you want to use the [snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) library. It can avoid issues,  like the one you mention, when moving SVG elements within SVGs, and complete SVGs within the DOM.